# Prove that the sequence $a_{n+1} = 2a_{n} - (a_{n})^2$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Prove that the sequence $a_{0} = \frac{1}{2}, a_{n+1} = 2a_{n} - (a_{n})^2$ is bounded.

Assume that $0 < a_{n} < 1$ for every $n$ and $a_{0} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Prof. used induction to prove that the sequence is bounded.

Base case $n = 1: 1 > \frac{1}{2}$ holds true. Then for the induction step $(n \rightarrow n+1)$ he wrote:

$a_{n+1} = a_{n}(2 - a_{n})$, so $a_{n+1} > 0$.

$1 - a_{n+1} = (a_{n})^2 - 2a_{n} + 1 = (a_{n} - 1)^2 > 0$

And therefore the sequence is bounded. So he manipulated the expression so that it can be written as $(a_{n} - 1)^2 > 0$, right? What was the point of doing so? So what is the sequence bounded by? The definition of boundedness is there exists some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|a_{n}| \leq M$. But what's the $M$ in this case? Is it $0$?

Comment: Since $0<a_n<1$ for any $n$ the bound of $|a_n|$ is $M=1.$

Comment: I also wonder the same thing... if he assumes $0 < a_n < 1$ for every $n$, isn't he assuming that $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is already bounded?

Comment: The correct way to write the start of the induction step is to assume $0<a_k < 1$ only for $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n$ and then go ahead and show that it holds for $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: @Winther I see. But how does showing $(a_{n} - 1)^2 > 0$ show that it holds for $a_{n+1}$? What about the $a_{n+1} < 1$ part?

Comment: Look at the full equation: $1 - a_{n+1} = (a_n-1)^2$. Now since we always have $(a_n-1)^2 > 0$ it follows that $1 - a_{n+1} > 0$ which just says that $a_{n+1} < 1$. This step does prove the thing you are trying to prove.

Comment: @Winther Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not *assume* that $0<a_n<1$, that is what you need to *prove* by induction. The only thing that you assume is that $a_{0} = \frac{1}{2}$, and $a_{n+1} = 2a_{n} - (a_{n})^2$ for all $n$.

So professor proved $a_{n+1}>0$ i.e. $0<a_{n+1}$, and 
$1-a_{n+1}>0$, i.e. $a_{n+1}<1$, these two taken together give you that 
$0<a_{n+1}<1$. That is starting with $0<a_0=\frac12<1$ and taking 
$0<a_n<1$ as the *induction hypothesis* you *prove* that $0<a_{n+1}<1$. 
It follows that $0<a_n<1$ for all $n=0,1,2,...$.

So your sequence is bounded between $0$ and $1$. There are different ways to express that a sequence is bounded, one is to say that all its members belong to some intervals $[p,q]$, e.g. all elements of the above sequence belong to the interval $[0,1]$. Another way (looks different, but amounts to the same) is to say there is $M$ with $|a_n|\le M$ for all $n$, well in our case take $M=1$, it works. Indeed $0<a_n<1$ so then it also holds that $-1<a_n<1$ that is 
$|a_n|<1$ for all $n$.

Comment: You _do_ assume that $0<a_n<1$, just not for _every_ $n$ as OP has written. You assume this for some specific $n$, and then use it to prove it holds for $n+1$ as well.

Comment: If you ask me, you only assume, at the beginning, that $0<a_0<1$. Then later you prove that **IF** $0<a_n<1$ **THEN** $0<a_{n+1}<1$. You may say that at this step you (temporarily) assume that $0<a_n<1$, for the sake of the argument in the induction step, but this assumption is of a bit different character than the original assumption that is given for granted, that $0<a_0<1$. I guess that is what you mean, the _specific_ $n$ in your comment being $n=0$ (base case).

Comment: I only meant to propose what OP copied from the instructor was intended to be a statement of the induction hypothesis, which is a certain kind of assumption. And either OP or the instructor accidentally tacked on "for every $n$". And by specific $n$, I meant whatever $n$ you want, as long as it is not "all".

Comment: Yes, one usually says, when using induction, things like _assume_ $0<a_n<1$ for **some** $n$, and _prove it_ for $n+1$. But apparently something got mixed up in the process or teacher explaining/student taking notes since the OP wrote Assume that $0<a_n<1$ for **every** $n$, and this is what I meant when I wrote you are not supposed to assume,but to prove.

Answer (score 1):

$(1-a_{n+1})=(1-a_n)^2$

$u_n=(1-a_n) \implies u_{n+1}=u_n^2=u_{n-1}^4=u_{n-i}^{2^{i+1}}=\ldots=u_0^{2^{n+1}}=(1-a_0)^{2^{n+1}}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2^{n+1}}$ $\therefore a_n=1-\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2^{n}}$